Add variable "monthly" increments to a datetime column in pandas using another column
I have the following dataset and I simply want to add the monthly increments (from a column within the dataframe) to my date column (another column in my dataframe).
index monthly_increment     date
0          1             2018-12-01
1          2             2018-10-01
2          3             2018-12-01
3          4             2018-01-01
4          5             2018-06-01

I'm hoping to get a new column:

index new_date
0     2019-01-01
1     2018-12-01
2     2019-03-01
3     2018-05-01
4     2018-11-01

There are two relevant posts:

Using this post, but the timedelta does NOT take month increments
Using this post, but DateOffset does not take Series/dataframe column.

When I try using DateOffset I get a TypeError.
>> df['new_date'] = df['date']+ pd.DateOffset(df['monthly_increment'])

TypeError: `n` argument must be an integer, got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Is there any simple solution to this without using loops/lambda function? My hunch is pandas should have a straightforward solution to this. It is super easy in Spark.

Voting to reopen. This question shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate of this post. Adjusting the logic used there to Series.astype('timedelta64[M]'), as done by @alidalasmar in this answer below is not a correct way to reach the desired result.

Since you seem to be working with first days of the month, this solution seems promising: (df['date'].dt.to_period('M') + df['monthly_increment']).dt.to_timestamp().

@ouroboros1 I think converting to monthly period and then use the increments is the best solution. If the community re-opens the post I can post the solution.

You can do this with some manual date manipulations:
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

year = (df.date.dt.year + (df.date.dt.month + df.monthly_increment - 1) // 12)
month = (df.date.dt.month + df.monthly_increment - 1) % 12 + 1

pd.to_datetime(dict(year=year, month=month, day=df.date.dt.day))

#0   2019-01-01
#1   2018-12-01
#2   2019-03-01
#3   2018-05-01
#4   2018-11-01
#dtype: datetime64[ns]


Code
It looks like need a loop. In Pandas, you can solve the loop with apply.
df['new_date'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=x['monthly_increment']),
    axis=1
)

df:
   monthly_increment       date   new_date
0                  1 2018-12-01 2019-01-01
1                  2 2018-10-01 2018-12-01
2                  3 2018-12-01 2019-03-01
3                  4 2018-01-01 2018-05-01
4                  5 2018-06-01 2018-11-01


If you want to use a for loop, see the code below.
df['new_date'] = [
    date + pd.DateOffset(months=n) 
    for n, date in zip(df['monthly_increment'], df['date'])
]

same result

Example Code
code that generates the body's df as a data frame.
import pandas as pd
data = {'monthly_increment': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'date': ['2018-12-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-12-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-06-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


Not sure why this received a downvote. This is a correct way of doing this, +1. Though I imagine there will be a duplicate somewhere for this method rather than the suggested duplicate, which cannot be used to reach the desired result.

@ouroboros1 so there's no solution without using the lambda function or a slow for loop?

@Gobryas I think there isn't a strict solution that doesn't use a loop, because there is date that doesn't exist after a given month(e.g. 09/31 doesn't exist, which is 2 months after 07/31), but there are vectorization operations that can be used in certain situations (e.g. all days are fixed as 1 day as ouroboros1 said).

@PandaKim Great explanation! Please vote to re-open. If the community re-opens the post I can post the solution.
